Talker/Listener topic failure ros2
Running talker.py and listener.py from the demo_nodes of ros2 humble seems to be having an issue. Talker is publishing out, but the listener is not receiving. This issue seems to also impact ros2 multicast send/receive as nothing is ever received. I tried creating a sub from cmd and echoing it in another cmd terminal but that also seems to not work, and wont even populate in the ros2 topic list. Does anyone know if this is potentially a firewall issue? I tried ROS_DOMAIN=0 and ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1 but that did not seem to fix the issue. This is on windows11

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
